# Visual Studio 2017 remove/disable file nesting

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Is it possible, and if yes how, to remove/disable file nesting for specific file types.

In my case I do not want that .ts files are nested beneath .html files.
All I found is [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/10924407-option-to-disable-file-nesting-in-asp-net-5-mvc) request. Did someone figure it out how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent this by manually editing Visual Studio's `toolSettings.json` file found at

`C:\Users(youruser)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_(yourinstanceid)\toolSettings.json`

Removing the `.ts` array from the `extensionToExtension` section will prevent them from nesting under HTML documents.  You can do this for .js and .css files as well.

Note that this may be reset during a Visual Studio re-install or update.

Comment: The path for 2017 is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\{YOUR-VS-VERSION}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\toolSettings.json`

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017 v.15.6.0 appears to have changed the file name to `.filenesting.json`.

I'm using Enterprise edition. Your mileage may vary.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\{YOUR-VS-VERSION}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\.filenesting.json`

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this is the correct answer now.